# How to create TextInput with blur background in React Native

Tags: react-native, styles, expo, textinput

I have a problem with styling TextInput Block in React Native

My target is inputs with the same blur effect background + blur

[image: how TextInput should look]

Now my code is :

```
<View style={styles.controll}>
 <View style={styles.inputWrapper}>
    <BlurView intensity={10}>
       <TextInput style={styles.emailInput} />
    </BlurView>
 </View>
 <View style={styles.inputWrapper}>
    <BlurView intensity={10}>
        <TextInput style={styles.passInput} />
    </BlurView>
 </View>
</View>
```

I'm using Expo component BlurView
import { BlurView } from "expo-blur";

Design code is

```
background: rgba(20, 15, 38, 0.648579);
backdrop-filter: blur(44.119px);
border-radius: 20px
```

My styles are looking like:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  inputWrapper: {
    width: "100%",
    height: 75,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(20, 15, 38, 0.648579)",
    filter: "blur(44.119)",
    borderRadius: 20,
    position: "relative",
    overflow: "hidden",
    marginBottom: 25
  },

  emailInput: {
    height: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "transparent"
  },
  controll: {
    flex: 2,
    width: "100%",
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    alignItems: "center"
    // backgroundColor: "red"
  },

});
```

What styles or libraries should add to achieve the desired effect? Thanks!